# How to deal with "None" when I using sklearn-decisiontreeclassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I use sklearn to built a decisiontree,examples:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X,Y)
result = clf.predict(testdata)
```

X is the training input samples,if there is "None" in X,How to do with it?

Comment: typically all entries in your data need to be of numeric type. One way to treat missing values is to just impute them, and if you want, create a new boolean variable that encoded the imputed rows for a specific column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Decision Trees** and Ensemble methods like *Random Forests* (based on such trees) only accept numerical data since it performs splits on each node of the tree in order to minimize a given impurity function (entropy, Gini index ...)

If you have some categorical features or some `Nan` in your data, the learning step will throw an error.

To **circumvent** this :

- **Transform categorical** data into numerical data : to do this use for example a *One Hot Encoder*. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) is a link to `sklearn`'s documentation.

*Warning* : If you have a feature with a lot of categories (e.g. an `ID` feature) `OneHotEncoding` may lead to memory issues. Try to avoid encoding such features.

- **Impute** some values to the missing ones. Many strategies exist (mean, median, most frequent ...). [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) is a link to `sklearn`'s documentation.

Once you've done this **preprocessing**, you can fit your Decision Tree to your data.

Comment: Thanks~your answer help me very much!